# .NET Parallel write into file

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have threads that:

- Read part of a file
- Compress / Decompress this part (GZipStream)
- The resulting data is written to a new file with a certain position

[image: Async Write File]

Imagine that flows will be completed in the order of their numbers.
After De/Compress, the size of the data changed.

How to determine the position to write to a file?

Comment: What's `Path1.Size`? If you have a task that depends on a result of another task, you can't let it run in parallel, because..you don't know the result yet.

Comment: @Jens Initially, I calculate, how many  parts of 5000 bytes in the file. Each thread knows what part it works, and what size

Comment: @Jens And what do I wait when all the threads finish their work, and only then write the data?

Comment: Are you sure you want this? This makes the files only readable by your application, because of the format it creates for each section: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Gzip

Comment: Writing to a file is sequential anyways. Determine what your bottle neck is. E.g. Read the file, split it, start threads for each part that just GZip the part and return. Save the compressed parts again and when all threads are done, write them to the file. You just have to keep track on the order of the parts.

Comment: @Jens And if 32Gb file size?

Comment: @jens Threads run only in terms of available RAM and the number of processor threads

Comment: @Jens If I follow the performance of the procedure, what sense to use threads?

Comment: Then you have a problem. But I think I understand what you want to do, and your method is flawed (@Caramiriel is correct). You can't just concatenate different GZip stream outputs and expect it to be the same as compressing the whole file in a single one. I mean, you can try and write the individual results back out to temporary files to avoid holding them in memory. The whole ordeal is unlikely to be even faster due to all the overhead. Have you tested that?

Comment: @jens Temporary files are a not bad idea. I save every part of the file, and then in turn will write data to the output file.

Comment: @Jens  What do you think, what is the optimal size of the part?

Comment: Given that disk I/O is probably the bottleneck anyway, I am not sure that you would made any appreciable gain. However, you might consider using 3 threads. One the read the data from the disk, one to process the data and the final one to save the data. If both the source and destination are on the same disk, then then might fight one against the other (particularly on mechanical hard drive) and it might even be worst. In any case, you have to make some try and measure the performance on the actual system as the final result would be much dependant on the relative IO to CPU performance.

Comment: Usually if you want performance, you need to ensure that your block size is a power of 2 related to memory page size and disk sector size. If I need to handle very large file, I would probably use something between 8192 (2^13) and 65536 (2^16)